# Puzzles similar to Advent of Code for LaTeX

Tags: puzzle

It's December 26th; the [Advent of Code](https://adventofcode.com/2016) challenge has ended. And, coincidentally, it's *Boxing Day*, so what would be more natural than trying to solve some of the AoC puzzles in LaTeX!? ;-)

It turns out that some of them are not too difficult to solve, while others are basically impossible to do, because they already require heavy CPU or memory usage in optimized high-level programming language code.

So I'm wondering if there are similar sets of puzzles somewhere that are custom-tailored for being solved with TeX/LaTeX (LuaTeX doesn't count here). Do you know any such puzzles or challenges?

Comment: You can look on the [Programming Puzzles and Code Golf site](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) for some puzzles—e.g. here is [one question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/123378/golf-my-shakespeare-quote-references) which has a solution in LaTeX, and to which I contributed some suggestions.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: Many thanks! This site is actually quite fun (also beyond LaTeX), I didn't know about it.